# 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed when posting to the same HTML page

Tags: html, post, iis-7.5, http-status-code-405

HTML web page on IIS 7.5  the HTML page is just posting to itself.  Every time it post to itself it says 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

I find this really frustrating that IIS 7.5 won't let you post a simple html file out of the box.

I checked under handler mappings and there is nothing specific for HTML.  How do i add the mappings for just a simple html page so it can post ?